# Cannot GET /__cypress/src/index.html Cypress Component Test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I've seen a few of these posts on stack with no clear solution.  I'm trying to leverage Cypress's component testing with the following:

```js
import { GroupPage } from './group.page'

describe('StepperComponent', () => {
  it('mounts', () => {
    cy.mount(`<app-group></app-group>`, {
      declarations: [GroupPage],
    })
  })
})
```

I've also tried this way:

```js
import { LoginPage } from './login.page'

describe('LoginPage', () => {
  it('mounts', () => {
    cy.mount(LoginPage)
  })
})
```

I've updated my config file with the following per the instructions I've seen online regarding this issue:

```js
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "angular",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
    specPattern: "**/*.cy.ts",
    indexHtmlFile: "cypress/support/component-index.html",
    supportFile: "cypress/support/component.ts",
  },
```

```
"cypress": "^10.7.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
"@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
```

Here's the component I'm trying to test:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { PresentationsService } from 'src/app/utilities/presentations.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-traval-group',
  templateUrl: './traval-group.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./traval-group.page.scss'],
})
export class GroupPage implements OnInit {
  userInfo: any;
  auth: Auth;

  constructor(private presentService: PresentationsService,
              private userService: UserService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.auth = getAuth();
    this.userInfo = await this.userService.getUserInfo(this.auth.currentUser.uid);
  }

  createGroup() {
    if ((!this.userInfo) || (!this.userInfo.userInfo?.dateOfBirth)) {
      this.presentService.missingData("", "")
      return
    }
  }
}
```